# Showing suggestions for attributes within a function (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So this is sort of hard to word but I am going to try my best to make this understandable :)

I am making a command driven personal assistant (in extremly early stages of development) which basically the user can type in different commands or questions and the assistant will answer the question or complete the task. For example, if a user types into the textbox "What is the time?" a dialog will appear and it will contain the time within the dialog. So what I want is when a user types in (for example) "what" it will suggest "what is the time" because that is one of the attributes within the function (you will understand when I post the code).

Here is the javascript (sorry for the mess):

```
// JavaScript Document

function searchKeyPress(e){
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.keyCode == 13){
            document.getElementById('btn').click();
        }
}
function command() {
    var srchVar = document.getElementById("srch");
    var srch = srchVar.value;
    var expression = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
    var regex = new RegExp(expression);
    var t = srch;

    if(srch == '') { alert('Please do not leave the field empty!'); }

    else if(srch.indexOf('about') != -1) { alert('The function of this project is to complete simple tasks and sometimes answer simple questions. \n\nMade by Omar Latreche. \n\n(c) Copyright Omar Latreche 2015'); }

    else if(srch.indexOf('commands') != -1) { window.location = "commands.html"; }

    else if(srch.indexOf('time') != -1) { alert('The current time according to your computer is' + ShowTime(new Date())); }

    else if(srch.indexOf('what') != -1) { if (confirm('I can see that is a question. Would you like to search Google for the answer?') == true) { window.open('https://www.google.com/#q=' + srch, '_blank'); }
    else { /* Nothing */ }; }

    else if(srch.indexOf('when') != -1) { if (confirm('I can see that is a question. Would you like to search Google for the answer?') == true) { window.open('https://www.google.com/#q=' + srch, '_blank'); }
    else { /* Nothing */ }; }

    else if(srch.indexOf('where') != -1) { if (confirm('I can see that is a question. Would you like to search Google for the answer?') == true) { window.open('https://www.google.com/#q=' + srch, '_blank'); }
    else { /* Nothing */ }; }

    else if(srch.indexOf('why') != -1) { if (confirm('I can see that is a question. Would you like to search Google for the answer?') == true) { window.open('https://www.google.com/#q=' + srch, '_blank'); }
    else { /* Nothing */ }; }

    else if(srch.indexOf('how') != -1) { if (confirm('I can see that is a question. Would you like to search Google for the answer?') == true) { window.open('https://www.google.com/#q=' + srch, '_blank'); }
    else { /* Nothing */ }; }

    else if(srch.indexOf('who') != -1) { if (confirm('I can see that is a question. Would you like to search Google for the answer?') == true) { window.open('https://www.google.com/#q=' + srch, '_blank'); }
    else { /* Nothing */ }; }

    else if(srch.indexOf('?') != -1) { if (confirm('I can see that is a question. Would you like to search Google for the answer?') == true) { window.open('https://www.google.com/#q=' + srch, '_blank'); }
    else { /* Nothing */ }; }

    else if(srch === 'okay assistant') { alert('Hello! How can I help you?'); }

    else if(srch.indexOf('weather') != -1) { window.open('https://www.google.com/#q=weather', '_blank'); }

    else if(t.match(regex)) { window.open(srch, '_blank'); }

    else { if (confirm('I am sorry but I do not understand that command. Would you like to search Google for that command?') == true) { window.open('https://www.google.com/#q=' + srch, '_blank'); }
        else { /* Nothing */ }
    }
}
//Show time in 12hour format
var ShowTime = (function () {
    function addZero(num) {
        return (num >= 0 && num < 10) ? "0" + num : num + "";
    }

    return function (dt) {
        var formatted = '';

        if (dt) {
            var hours24 = dt.getHours();
            var hours = ((hours24 + 11) % 12) + 1;
            formatted = [formatted, [addZero(hours), addZero(dt.getMinutes())].join(":"), hours24 > 11 ? "PM" : "AM"].join(" ");            
        }
        return formatted;
    }
})();
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Tiny Assistant</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="cont_title">
    <span class="title">Tiny</span><span class="title2"> Assistant</span>
</div>
<div class="cont">
    <input name="srch" id="srch" class="search" spellcheck="false" onkeypress="searchKeyPress(event);" placeholder="Type &quot;Okay Assistant&quot;" type="text" />
</div>
<div style="margin-top:10px" class="cont">
    <!--<input type="submit" onClick="command();" class="button" value="Done" id="btn" />-->
    <button type="submit" id="btn" aria-label="Done" class="button" onClick="command();">
        <span class="btn_txt">Done</span>
    </button>
</div>
<div style="margin-top:10px" class="cont">
    <span class="info">&copy; Copyright Omar Latreche 2015. All rights reserved.</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am sorry for the essay but that is the only way I could think to word it. I hope you understand what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

Please do take a look at this:

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: It'll be much easier.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will test this to make sure it works but it looks promising!

Comment: Welcome. Make sure to import jquery.js and query-ui (http://jqueryui.com/download/all/ )for it to work!

Comment: What exactly is not working? Please be more specific or post your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81906/discussion-between-omar-latreche-and-guergana).

Comment: hey, sorry. I couldn't answer. You need to remove your previous code. It seems to be conflicting with the new one. Remove the innkeepers event and all your previous code.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand which part of my previous code I need to remove?

Comment: It seems that you now have both your previous code <input name="srch" id="srch" class="search" spellcheck="false" onkeypress="searchKeyPress(event);" placeholder="Type &quot;Okay Assistant&quot;" type="text"> and the command function AND the new code. Please remove or comment out your previous code. Remove the call to the onkeypress event in your <input>.  Also you need to put everything after "// Auto Complete" inside of a $( document ).ready(function() {
   /* EVERYTHING GOES HERE*/
}); Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Without the command function the assistant won't be able to answer the questions? And without the input how will the user input the text?

Comment: you don't need not to remove the input just the part that says onkeypress="searchKeyPress(event);" !

Comment: You need to go step by step. I think you need to split and test the jquery part separate from the answers (command) function.